# How to change the height of a button and a map when a bottomSheet expands and collapses

Tags: java, android

I have an app which contains a button , a map and a bottom sheet . The button is set at the top of the bottom sheet and when the bottom sheet expands it hides the button. What I want is when the bottom sheet expands the height of the button and the map changes by the same value the bottom sheet changed with.
(I know the value by which the button and map should be translated by but i dont know how to implement that , the value is 110 dp)

[collapsed bottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68syo.png)

[expanded bottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeN6Y.png)

**Java Code**

```
controlButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.controlButton);

bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight((int) getApplicationContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.Card_View_Height));
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        bottomSheet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Card_View_Height is the value by which i need the button height to change with

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?